# Word for making a dataset

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Suppose that there exists a dataset consisting 1.5m scientific papers. I have done a lot of processing on the table to mitigate the noises in it, handling null values, etc. My extensive work resulted in a much cleaner dataset (of 650k papers). What word can I use:

We ... a dataset consisting 650k papers.

Possible candidates:

- made
- compiled
- built

Comment: If the result of your work is a cleaner data set, then you *cleaned up* the existing data set and *produced* a new data set consisting **of** 650,000 papers.

Comment: If you had created a dataset from scratch, then your words seem OK; I would add ***constructed*** to the list. In the case you describe, I would say that you ***refined*** the existing dataset.

Comment: The point is that the cleaning is an important part and the result is valuable. In other words, the dataset can itself be published as a new dataset with a meaningful added value. So, e.g., using only cleaned up is somehow weak in this context.

Comment: What's wrong with *processed* ?

Comment: I sense that processing is more related to a process not the product. In other words, it does not emphasize that the product is a special and useful result. For example, I sense that a word like compile (without considering whether natives use that in this context), means we built something and is focused on the result not the process: e.g., in "We compiled a dataset by performing extensive data cleaning on dataset X"

Answer (score 4):

Another possibility is **[curate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/curate)**. "We curated a dataset consisting of 650k papers."

> Select, organize, and present (online content, merchandise,
>   information, etc.), typically using professional or expert knowledge.

An example from "[Genomics Needs A Killer App](https://techcrunch.com/2015/03/27/genomics-needs-a-killer-app/)":

> Traditionally, much of this information has been distributed through
>   academic publications. Many companies **curate** papers to extract
>   valuable information for clinical genomic and R&D applications:
>   Ingenuity, Biobase, Thomson Reuters, and others.

Answer (score 2):

I like @michael.hor257k's suggestion, but you could also use *munged* (sounds like monger in fishmonger). From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mung_%28computer_term%29):

> Mung or munge is computer jargon for a series of potentially destructive or irrevocable changes to a piece of data or a file. It is sometimes used for vague data transformation steps that are not yet clear to the speaker. Common munging operations include removing punctuation or html tags, data parsing, **filtering**, and transformation. …
>   **Munging can also describe the processing or filtering of raw data into another form.**

I often say I've *munged some data*, or *cleaned it up*. There are also several books on how to [*data mung*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2/252-8578617-7444543?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=data+munging), so it's a well known term (among people who *mung*:) for this sort of thing.

Comment: Huh, never saw that one before—very useful word!

Answer (score 1):

There are domain-specific technical terms (verbs) to denote the actions mentioned by the OP like [**cleansing**, **scrubbing**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_cleansing), **[wrangling](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/08/18/technology/for-big-data-scientists-hurdle-to-insights-is-janitor-work.html?_r=1)** and **munging** (this one is already mentioned in another answer) but I am not sure if they fit in the example sentence as it is. Perhaps it can be adapted like:

> We ***cleansed/scrubbed/wrangled/munged*** the dataset of 1.5m scientific papers into a smaller one of 650k papers.

Also, ***distilled*** connotes reduction (1.5m to 650k) *and* improvement (processing on the table to mitigate the noises in it, handling null values, etc):

> We ***distilled*** a dataset consisting of 650k papers.

M-W:

> **[distill](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distill)**
> *verb*
>
> : **to take** the most important **parts** of something and put them in a
> different and usually **improved** form
>
> He has perfectly distilled the meaning of the holiday into a poem.

A widely accepted and understood term would be ***prepared*** (as in data preparation).

> We ***prepared*** a dataset consisting of 650k papers.

M-W:

> **[prepare](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prepare)**
> *verb*
>
> : to make (someone or something) ready for some activity, purpose,
> use, etc.
>
> : to make or create (something) so that it is ready for use
>
> The pharmacist prepared the prescription.

Another generic(nontechnical) term would be ***extracted***.

> We ***extracted*** a dataset consisting of 650k papers.

M-W:

> **[extract](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/extract)** *verb*
>
> : to get (something, such as information) from something
>
> Investigators were able to extractuseful information from the
> company's financial records.
>
> They are hoping to extract new insights from the test results

.

Answer (score 0):

*"You condensed the data set."*

***Condense*** — [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/condense)

> *verb* To reduce something, such as a speech or piece of writing, in length
>   *"I condensed ten pages of comments into/to two."*

Answer (score 0):

If you are speaking of choosing 650K papers from 1.5M papers, then you have [culled](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cull) the papers:

**cull**, transitive verb

> to select from a group : choose *culled the best passages from the poet's work*
>
> to reduce or control the size of (as a herd) by removal (as by hunting) of especially weaker animals; also :  to hunt or kill (animals) as a means of population control

I'm a little unclear as to whether you are controlling the papers (which themselves comprise your data) or the data contained within the papers. I might use *cull* for controlling papers, or *cleanse* the data within the papers. For example:

> We culled the papers that were not peer reviewed or that had a p-value of greater than .01.
>
> We cleansed the data of the papers that did not take patient's age or socioeconomic status into account.

Answer (score -1):

> We *assembled* a dataset consisting 650k papers.

Comment: Assemble sounds more like building something up, rather than condensing it down to the essential bits. Your answer could use a reference as well, maybe I am mistaken.

Comment: @Helmar to me, *assemble* is similar to "making a collection".  If I assemble all my ingredients on the kitchen table before starting to cook, I'll have a calmer process than if I scramble to look for them as I go.  (You are right, I should have provided a reference.)